Как поставить реакцию на сообщение Telegram ботом в C#? Telegram.Bot
Я написал простенького бота с использованием библиотеки Telegram.Bot. Теперь хочу поставить реакцию на сообщение. Недавно это добавили в API ботов. Функция "setMessageReaction". Но беда  в том, что библиотека Telegram.Bot не обновляется с мая 2023. Она не знает эту функцию. Как мне отправить реакцию через API? Получится ли это совместить с текущим проектом построенном на Telegram.Bot?
Или может, вообще, есть более удобная библиотека для C#?
Visual studio 2022
C#
Пакет: Telegram.Bot

Не смотрите только NuGet, ищите официальные источники и изучайте их на наличие новых версий или "форков". Если зайти на GitHub проекта, то увидите, что он все еще развивается (последняя правка месяц назад, а последняя альфа вышла 3 марта), ну а если поискать нужный вам функционал, то и вовсе увидим, что он вроде как реализован. Так что, вам надо просто скачать версию с GitHub и использовать ее.

Опасаюсь альфа версий

Можете и сами реализовать

Пока не могу. Я нуб.

От нас тогда вы что хотите? Я вам говорю, что библиотека имеет уже то, что вам надо, в ответ получаю "боюсь"; вам пишут "реализуйте сами", в ответ "я нуб" (хотя кстати в вопросе вы это и просите). Удаляйте тогда вопрос, раз вам ничего не нужно...

Нашел библиотеку Telegram.BotAPI. Она умеет ставить реакции на сообщения и в целом поддерживает самую последнюю версию Telegram API. Не могу разобраться как написать ReactionType.

Попробовал поставить альфа версию библиотеки Telegram.Bot. Но почему-то метод SetMessageReactionAsync у меня так и не появился.
В итоге пришлось через Telegram API вручную этим методом воспользоваться. Хотел код вставить, но не влазит(

static private async Task SetReactionAsync(long chatId, int messageId, string emoji)         {             string url = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/setMessageReaction";             var data = new             {                 chat_id = chatId,                 message_id = messageId,                 reaction = new[]                 {                 new { type = "emoji", emoji = emoji }             },                 is_big = true             };

Ваша проблема сейчас в невнимательности! Я вам ведь что сказал? Цитата: "вам надо просто скачать версию с GitHub и использовать ее", а вы альфу от куда скачали? NuGet? Ну а то, что там Альфа 1, а не Альфа 3 вас не смущает? Еще раз повторю - с GitHub! Прям берете, качаете исходных код (папка src/Telegram.Bot) и добавляете в свое решение, потом ПКМ по "ссылки/зависимости" у конкретного проекта "добавить ссылку на проект" - галка напротив нужного пакета. Все, будет у вас нужный метод. Пожалуйста, будьте внимательней, а не читайте между строк...

Через библиотеки не смог решить задачу. Пришлось вручную сделать через Telegram API:
static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        //Отправка реакции вручную через Telegram API
        static private async Task SetReactionAsync(long chatId, int messageId, string emoji)
        {
            string url = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/setMessageReaction";
            var data = new
            {
                chat_id = chatId,
                message_id = messageId,
                reaction = new[]
                {
                new { type = "emoji", emoji = emoji }
            },
                is_big = true
            };

            var jsonData = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            // Отправим запрос к API
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, jsonData);

            // Обработаем ответ
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка при попытке поставить реакцию.");
                Console.WriteLine($"Код ошибки: {response.StatusCode}");
                string errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Текст ошибки: {errorResponse}");
            }
        }


Ох как все запущено) Ну чтож, ваше право, ваше право... Единственное, прочитайте про HttpClient, увидите что он должен быть создан один раз и жить все время существования приложения. У вас сейчас он создается каждый раз при вызове метода, а еще аналогичный клиент внутри библиотеки используется. Если не плевать на оптимизацию, скорость, и так далее, то советую и под библиотеку и под ваш код использовать 1 клиент. А еще лучше, обновить библиотеку, а не изобретать костылей...

@EvgeniyZ, благодарю. Исправил код.
